# Convert a date string specifying the pattern in Pharo 8

Tags: date, smalltalk, pharo

`'04/30/2019' asDate` works, but `'30/04/2019' asDate` fails because the date format of this date is in the `'dd/MM/yyyy'` format.

How do I specify different time format in Pharo 8?

Comment: If you can write it in English, try `'April 30, 2019' asDate`. Otherwise use `Date year: 2019 month: 4 day: 30`

Comment: I have a string input in non english format and I cannot change that. To do as you said, I would have to parse my date string into three numbers, that don't seems reasonable, as date conversion using pattern is wildly used and much more elegant. This is not possible in Pharo?

Comment: Then try `Date readFrom: '30/4/2019' readStream pattern: 'dd/m/yyyy'`. Note that `'m'` will accept both 1 and 2 month indexes.

Comment: Thanks, there is something similar to DateAndTime also?

Comment: If you can add it all in an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to get a `Date` from a `String`. In your case, one that would work is the following

```
   Date readFrom: '30/4/2019' readStream pattern: 'dd/m/yyyy'
```

The `'m'` in the pattern will match two digit month indexes too. If you use `'mm'` instead your month indexes must have two digits, e.g., `'04'`.

There is nothing similar for `DateAnTime`. However you can do the following:

```
   | stream |
   stream := '30/4/2019 18:11:03' readStream.
   date := Date readFrom: (stream upTo: $ ) readStream pattern: 'dd/m/yyyy'.
   time := Time readFrom: stream.
   ^DateAndTime date: date time: time.
```

This uses the first part of the stream (up to the space) for the date and then continues with the time. Note that the stream is left at the character next to the space, which should be where the time begins.